# I have to test Java

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I was told in my class that I have to write and test my code in the main method, I wrote it, but I dont know how to test it. How I am supposed to test my methods?  I am supposed to take user input, and then get the get the first letter, last letter, etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Word
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    }

    public String word;

    public void Word()
    {
        String word = "";
    }

    public void Word(String word1)
    {
        String word = word1;
    }

    public String getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }   

    public void setWord(String newWord)
    {
        String word = newWord;
    }

    public void getFirstLetter()
    {
        String firstLetter = word.substring(0, 1);
    }

    public void getLastLetter()
    {
        String lastLetter = word.substring(word.length() - 1, word.length());
    }

    public void removeFirstLetter()
    {
        String noFirstLetter = word.substring(1, word.length());
    }

    public void removeLastLetter()
    {
        String noLastLetter = word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
    }
    public int findLetter (String parameter)
    {
        word.indexOf(parameter);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but not for school, this is for an outside of school class.

Comment: Start by putting some code in your main method, perhaps. Create Word objects and call methods and such.

Comment: <yorkshire_accent>Ah, the youth of today -- you don't know how lucky you have it! When i was learning programming, we had to write our code on paper, translate to fortran, create punch cards from the code, then submit our punch cards to the computing laboratory for an over-night run. Then debug and repeat the whole process again!</yorkshire_accent> Now-a-days, you've got your computing laboratory right on your desktop in your very own home -- so **experiment**! Create code, bad code, good code, any code! Just create, test, modify, and above all, ***try***!

Answer (score 2):

You test your methods by calling them with some defined input and compare the results with your expected output.

Example:

Suppose you have a method like this:

```
public static int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

You'd test it like this:

```
int result = add( 3, 5);
if( result != 8 ) {
  //method is wrong
}
```

So basically you define a "contract" of what input the method gets and what the result should be (in terms of return value or other changed state). Then you check whether you get that result for your input and if so you can assume the method works correctly.

In order to be quite sure (you often can't be perfectly sure) you'd test the method several times with different types of input (as many as reasonable, to test different cases, e.g. short words, long words).

You often also test how your method handles wrong input, e.g. by passing null or empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at tools like [junit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

You can create a simple Test class and test your class and its behavior.

```
imports ...;

public class MyTest{

    @Test
    public void testMyClass(){
        Word w= new Word();
        w.setWord("test");
        Assert.assertEquals(w.getFirstLetter(), "t");
    }
}
```

With tools like Eclipse you could nicely run such a test.

Comment: I just figured that your getFirstLetter actually isn't a getter. However this should show how testing could be done in general...

Comment: Except because `getFirstLetter()` has a return type of `void`, the test code won't compile.  But I agree, he should learn how to use JUnit (or similar); it'd point out all the problems his code has right off (once the return type is changed, the test will end up getting NPEs)

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint: you're very close you need an instance of Word, than you can call your methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Word test = new Word();
      test.setWord("something");
      // here you might read javadoc of the String class on how to compare strings
}
```

EDIT:
I overlooked this:

```
public void setWord(String newWord)
{
     String word = newWord;
}
```

The code you've written creates a variable `word` and newWord is assigned to it and then disappears.
If you (obviously) want to set a member of a class you should use `this` wich references the instance (you created in main()).

```
public void setWord(String newWord) {
   this.word = newWord;
}
```

Comment: So test.setWord("somthing"); could be user input with the scanner?

Comment: Well this is what I had, then when I printed test.word it would print "null"

Comment: @Jerryg225 "something" needs to be a String from whatever source. 2nd I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since I would say this is homework, I will try not to explicitly give the answer.  In the main method, you should set your word, then call each method and print the output to verify it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jason. If you wanna test something, simply `System.out.println()` it. In your methods though, your return type is not a `String` but a `void`, so you could change that, and print it out on the main program `run`.

If not, just put the `System.out.println()` in your `void` methods. Shouldn't have much of a problem!